# In Langevin equation of stochastic oscillator, can the system has only fluctuation force with no fraction?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, diffusion, stochastic-processes

I am new to fluctuation statistical mechanics, In all examples that I encountered, the Langevin equation always has the fluctuation force accompanied by a friction force.
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\gamma \frac{dx}{dt}+w_o^2 x=f(t)$$
From Fokker-Plank formula, I can see that if the system has no dissipation or fraction, then the mean square velocity of the system will grow linearly with time. Does this mean that oscillators with only diffusion can not reach equilibrium at $t->\infty$

Comment: A system can reach an equilibrium state if it satistifies the fluctuation dissipation theorem (or Einstein relation). The fluctuation dissipation theorem constrains the covariance of the noise to be related to the damping indeed if the damping coeff is $\gamma$ then the noise covariance must be: $\langle f(t) f(t')\rangle=2\gamma k_bT$. Hence, in your case, if your system does not have damping, it cannot describe an equilibrium system.

Comment: @Syrocco, You answered my question, thank you